# how to set a button on the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to set a button on the map like in this image and define it's position with Lat/Lng coordinates?

Or is there another way how to set the Position of the button?

[image: Button / cluster map]

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please focus on 1 problem only. See [ask]. Regarding 1) there are many ways you could do that (HTML Marker, Marker + infowindow, HTML button) 2) Not natively 3) There are many different sources, with various level of details and therefore various sizes.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls

Comment: [google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom)

Comment: Now that you have reduced your question to one problem, have you tried anything that I suggested? HTML Marker (OverlayView) - there are examples in the documentation as well as many tutorials that you can easily find with a web search. The [MapsCanvasProjection Interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapCanvasProjection) has methods to convert from coords to DOM positions and vice versa.

Comment: Also as mentioned by @geocodezip, you *could* center the map over the country you are interested in and use a custom control, but there is no `CENTER_CENTER` position available.

Comment: Thats's not really what I'm looking for. I don't want to create an overlay control, I want to create a button on a fixed LatLng position. Instead of this function "map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER]" I need a function like this "map.controls[{ lat: 46.86036800873809, lng: 8.126608108250018 }]"
@MrUpsidown I'm still trying to find out, how the MapsCanvasProjection works, but I only get errors back. I really don't understand what I can do with these functions, but I'm trying to find out.

Comment: 3rd time now that I mention you can use an HTML Marker which you can build using the [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) and as I said, there are multiple tutorials around ([this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-custom-html-markers-on-google-maps-9ff21be90e4b) is one) which should probably also shed some light on how to use the MapsCanvasProjection. Stack overflow is not a learning center... You must do your own research and come here if you have a technical/coding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments!

The OverlayView was a little bit to complex for my purpose, so I found another solution.

```
let FormCH = {
    path: 'M -3,-0.5 3,-0.5 3,0.5 -3,0.5 z ',
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#99d126',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: 30
};

let markerCH = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
        lat: 46.818188,
        lng: 8.227511999999999
    },
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: FormCH,
    label: {
        text: "Switzerland " + numCH,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: "20px",
        color: "#fff"
    }
});
```

I set a marker with a label text and replaced the marker icon with a svg path.

Here's the result:
[code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pnfz.png)

But as you can see, there's some space around the green box. You can resize it in "path:" or you find a way how to auto resize the box.

When I find a solution how to automatically resize the box I will post it here.